# how to enable or disable many print statements in python with log?

Tags: python, if-statement, debugging, comments

the code looks like this - has many prints for debug purposes. I want to have some toggle 'button' , one liner that enables/disables those print statements. without commenting out/in.

```
#age
            if (row['age'] < 25.0):
                print()
                print('age < 25')
                score += -45.0
                print('score changed to : %d ' % score)

            elif (row['age'] >= 25.0) and (row['age'] < 29.0):
                print()
                print('25 < age < 29')
                score += -22.0
                print('score changed to : %d ' % score)

            elif (row['age'] >= 29.0) and (row['age'] < 35.0):
                print()
                print('29 < age < 35')
                score += 1.0
                print('score changed to : %d ' % score)

            elif (row['age'] >= 35.0):
                print()
                print('age > 35')
                score += 19.0
                print('score changed to : %d ' % score)

            #f27
            if (row['f27']== ''):                
                print()
                print('f27 missing found')
                score += -18.0
                print('score changed to : %d ' % score)
```

Comment: Go for python logging and disable/enable logging level to None

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope code below will help you.

```
from __future__ import print_function
debug  = True
def print(*args, **kwargs):
     if(debug):
             return __builtin__.print(*args, **kwargs)
```

The above code will override the builtin print function.
it prints if debug set to True otherwise it skips print.

Comment: wow thx but how is it called? is there separate print function out theere or is it called overloading print function?

Comment: It is a separate print function calling system print function, so that you don't have to change your code.